# Why does inspect.getsource throw TypeError when trying to get source for Python Built-in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

What is the difference between a python built-in and a normal object? we often say that in python everything is an object. 
for example, when I do this in Python 3.6:

```
>>> import os, inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(os.scandir)
TypeError: <built-in function scandir> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

I have two questions:

1. is built-in function an object? if not is this why getsource throws TypeError?
2. why can't I find scandir in [python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a built-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the source of builtins and other modules that were written using the C API, since there isn't a Python source for them.

From the documentation for [**`inspect.getsourcefile(object)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile):

> Return the name of the Python source file in which an object was defined. **This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function.**

Comment: you have a point, but still my two question wasn't answered. and furthering your point, where can I find the C source code for that?

Comment: The answer to your second question is that `scandir` is *not* a builtin that is always available, so of course it's not listed there.

Comment: ok, but IMHO it would be better to list it there and provide highlighted description of availability scope. unless that‘s too much hassle for open source ofc. :D

Comment: The link you posted refers to builtins that are *always* available in Python, without any imports required.  Adding functions that *do* require inputs would quickly muddle that list.

Comment: and my first question, are built-ins objects? if they're not, wouldn't that violates basic principle of python?